# Bash - DoWhile - Read a File content

Tags: bash, unix

I need a huge favor from you.

I have to run several times a PHP script, but I have no knowledge of programming in bash.

The script should work like this:

Within a cycle DoWhile ->

- Execute PHP script directory / crawler.php,
- I read the contents of the directory / array.txt
- If the content is equal to 0 then I get out of the loop (break;)
- If the content is different from 0 then the continuous cycle

The script directory / crawler.php must be tested at least once.

Some of you know how to write this code in Bash?
Bash For those who know the code is really simple, but it is very difficult for me because I do not know anything Bash.

I just need this script in my "bash-programming-life. "

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
php directory/crawler.php
while [[ "$(cat directory/array.txt)" -ne "0" ]]; do
  php directory/crawler.php
done
```

presuming that the directory/array.txt file only contains a 0 when execution should terminate.

Comment: I get this error:

tv2db.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
tv2db.sh: line 5: `done'

Comment: RESOLVED: I tried to use "pico" instead of trasfering file via FTP and all works! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
file=directory/array.txt

>>"$file"    # create the file if it doesn't exist

until [[ "$(<"$file")" == "0" ]]
do
  php directory/crawler.php
done
```

Comment: : command not found
: command not found
tv2db.sh: line 6: syntax error in conditional expression
'v2db.sh: line 6: syntax error near `]]
'v2db.sh: line 6: `until [[ "$(<"$file")" == "0" ]]

Comment: @Leonardo: Are you sure that your shebang line is as shown in my answer and you're not running the script like: `sh v2db.sh` (`bash v2db.sh` would be OK as would a simple `./v2db.sh` if you did `chmod +x v2db.sh` and have the correct shebang in place).